# Unable to scroll down to the bottom when hiding/unhiding an element

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, scroll

I have been having this issue for a week now where I use `animate()` and `display none` to hide/unhide an element.

Then the page height is then decreased for hiding the element(opacity 0/display none) and then the page height comes back to normal when the hidden element is shown(opacity 1/display ), and this is where the scroll goes weird, i cannot scroll down to the bottom of the page.
I can only scroll to the last minimum height that the page was modified by the hidden elements. the other height that was added back is not scrollable. 
when i tried this on desktop its fine but in smartphone its not working properly.

Here is my code:

Hide

```
$('.parentTR').animate(
    {opacity: 0}, 500, function () {
        $('.parentTR').css('display', 'none')});
```

Show

```
$('.parentTR').css('overflow', 'auto').css('display', '').animate(
    {opacity: 1}, 800);
```

test environment:
-iphone
-safari
-sharepoint

Cheers

Comment: Please post all of your codes.